# How to output type definitions in vs2015 community

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

I am trying to output types definition(appBundle.d.ts) file in vs2015 community.
I have seen that there is a compiler option '--declaration', so i tried to just add it into the tsconfig.json file like following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": "www/scripts/appBundle.d.ts", // <------
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

But it's not working; the appBundle.js is beeing generated as expected, but appBundle.d.ts is not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `declaration` option can be either `true` or `false`.
Check out [the tsconfig.json schema](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig).